# What kind of model can be suitable for predicting 100 values from 25 values by using a Neural Network in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, tensorflow

Previously I used **Sequential** model for this problem, but later I read from the TensorFlow website that it is not suitable to use it. I'd like to have a NN model to predict 100+ values from the given 25 values. The code below is my previous implementation. What kind of changes should I make to achieve better results?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split( 
    inputdata, outputdata, test_size=0.2)


model = tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(25)))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(103))

model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="adam",
          metrics=["mean_squared_error"])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20)
predictions = model.predict(predict)
```

Comment: A sequential model is perfectly fine in total lack of any other information. Maybe you can tell us what these 25 values and 100+ values mean and what is their relationship, and a link to the place where you read that a sequential model is not suitable for this.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model       Please, see the section where it is mentioned that it is not appropriate (Any of your layers has multiple inputs or multiple outputs). Maybe I misunderstood it. Those are band values of a hyperspectral image. Those 100 values were passed through multiple processes and became 25 (values changed completely) and I need to recover the previous 100 from 25. It is a sort of compression and decompression. I can't say they have a strong relation between at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Tensorflow documentation that you linked, "multiple inputs/outputs", refers to multiple input/output **tensors**. Here you have one input tensor (of size 25) and one output tensor (of size 100+).

Comment: Thank you for the information. But what is the algorithm here? Is it backpropagation? What is it exactly? It works but I can't understand what it is.

Comment: Yes, it's backpropagation. All the main neural network frameworks nowadays use backpropagation.

Comment: Thank you very much!